# Git Pulling and Fetching on a branch of a branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

Git newbie here, using Visual Studio rather than command line to issue commands.
My understanding of a good branching strategy is we have a "main" in the repository. We then have a "dev" branch from main which all developers work from.
To implement changes we branch from "dev" branch then check back in to "dev" when work is complete via pull requests.
Once "dev" work is completed after several weeks, "dev" is merged into "main".

[image]

What I'm struggling to satisfy myself is that if i'm working on my local branch (from "dev"), and I fetch or pull in Visual Studio to bring it up to date with other developers changes, i expect it to pull from "dev" as that is what i branched from originally. There is nothing to show in Visual Studio Synchronisation that is what it is doing.

It just says "*Pulling changes for the local branch*" and this is all it shows:

[image]

**Can anyone clarify in this scenario that it will pull/fetch from originating branch i.e. "dev" and not the "main"?** I've looked all over but cannot find anything that convinces me, i suspect it will be clearer using some command line tool.

Comment: After branching out with `git checkout -b`, it's no longer the same branch anymore and does not "default pull" from the same upstream. You can always run `git merge origin/dev` after `git remote update` to manually pull in the latest changes.

Comment: I would suggest you install TortoiseGit. I find it a lot more intuitive in usage than the Visual Studio git functions, and it supports 99.9% of the commands you'll ever need.

Comment: @iBug - thanks the point of this strategy is to have "main" which is a copy of live. "dev" is all the work we do for a release and the idea is by 'pulling' in our own branches we can bring in each developers changes that are in "dev" so merge conflicts can be resolved. As we are not checking in pull requests into "main" then doing a pull wont bring in changes from other completed branches. Should this be done differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull` (or the equivalent GUI command) updates the current branch to the latest version on the server. Therefore, this usually only does something when you are on develop or master, or in the rare case when multiple developers are working on a feature branch.

`git fetch` pulls all changes to all branches from the server, but does *not* update your working copy. Typically, you'll look at the history after a git fetch and manually update your working copy, either by merging develop to your working branch or (more commonly) by rebasing your working copy on the latest dev branch. In visual studio, you can do the merge by right-clicking on a branch (other than the current) and executing the "merge branch to current branch" command. To rebase your branch on another, choose "Rebase current branch on"

Here's how the menu looks like (sorry, only got a german screenshot, but you should get the point)

[image: Context Menu for branch operations]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The main point of my question is does a pull or fetch come from "main" or from the "dev" branch which i created my branch from. It sounds like the answer is "main".

Comment: pull updates the _current_ branch, regardless of where it was branched from. Since your work branches typically don't update unless you update them yourself, pull is actually rarely used when you work with work branches. fetch on the other hand updates the local repo, but does not update any branches. Therefore, the answer to your question is "neither".

Comment: thank you @PMF I understand now. Regards.